# How to replace multiple var keywords by the real types in selected text?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

`var` keyword in C# is pretty useful, since it is much shorter to write and does not change the compiled program. Hovering over `var` keyword in Visual Studio shows a tool tip with the "real" variable type behind, which is nice too.

But in most of the cases, having full qualified type instead of `var` makes code more readable. When there are ten `var`s in ten lines of code, each one having its own underlying type, it becomes more difficult to quickly understand the source code.

Is there an add-in or a tool which replaces all `var`s by explicitly defined variable types in selected text?

Comment: See [Resharper: vars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296783/resharper-vars) and [Tool to refactor C# var to explicit type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289743/tool-to-refactor-c-var-to-explicit-type).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool to refactor C# var to explicit type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289743/tool-to-refactor-c-var-to-explicit-type)

Comment: I don't happen to agree with the premise, but aside from that, I should probably point out that not all instances of `var` can be replaced.  In specific, there's no equivalent way to refer to anonymous types.  I'm sure you find this obvious, but I'm commenting on this for others.

Comment: Old thread, I was actually searching on how to do the reverse. I think var is preferrable because it removes duplication. eg "MyWindow window = new MyWindow()". If we want to change to use SomeOtherWindow then we need to change it in 2 places. Surely that is not a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[Resharper.](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)