# Using implicit typing

Tags: c#, resharper, implicit-typing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resharper: vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296783/resharper-vars)

Is there a reason that resharper suggests `var thing1 = 5` as opposed to `int thing1 = 5`? It just seems that they mean the exact same thing except that var is harder/less comprehensible to a human reader. I would be curious to know if there is a difference in the way that the compiler interprets them, or if its just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the generated IL will be *exactly* the same.

I suspect if you take up Resharper's suggestion, it will *also* "suggest" going the other way - IIRC the default is to always offer the ability to change in either direction. You can change what it suggests within the options though.

Comment: Wow, ReSharper is one mean troll. "Use `var`" *-uses `var`-* "No, no no, use `int`!" *-uses `int`-* "No, use `var`!"

Answer (score 5):

Usage of the 'var' keyword tends to be controversial.  The 'authoritative' reference for this debate is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/20/uses-and-misuses-of-implicit-typing.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The reason that ReSharper is suggesting you use `var` is that it is by default configured to do so.

Go into the options for ReSharper, find the "Inspection Severity" settings under "Code Inspection", and a ways down into that list, find the setting labelled "Use 'var' keyword when possible".

ReSharper will, with the default setting of "Show as suggestion", by default suggest you use `var` instead of the actual type if:

- You're constructing an object (ie. `Type x = new Type(...);`)
- You're initializing it with a constant (ie. `int x = 5;`)

In both of these cases, ReSharper is programmed to assume that you can easily spot the correct type anyhow, so you can use `var`.

If you don't want that, change that setting. You can also change that setting directly in the dropdown you get from Alt+Enter, just pick the bottom item in the dropdown menu:

[image: Alt+Enter dropdown menu]

and it will pop open a dialog asking how to treat that setting:

[image: Dialogbox]

Also note that if you ask ReSharper to change the code to using `var`, it won't suggest you turn it back, but you *can*, by hitting Alt+Enter again and picking the option "Specify type explicitly".