# Convert to Method Group Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper

I have written a method below like this:

```
internal static IList<EmpowerTaxView> GetEmpowerTaxViewsByLongAgencyAndAgencyTaxTypes(
   IList<EmpowerCompanyTaxData> validEmpowerCompanyTaxDatas,
   IList<EmpowerTaxView> empowerTaxViews)
{
    IList<EmpowerTaxView> result = new List<EmpowerTaxView>();

    foreach (EmpowerCompanyTaxData empowerCompanyTaxData in validEmpowerCompanyTaxDatas)
    {
         IList<EmpowerTaxView> validEmpowerTaxViews =
           GetEmpowerTaxViewsByLongAgencyAndTaxType(
             empowerCompanyTaxData, empowerTaxViews);

         validEmpowerTaxViews.ToList().ForEach(delegate(EmpowerTaxView etv)
         {
              result.Add(etv);   
         });   
    }

    return result;
}
```

And for this method, the resharper says:

```
validEmpowerTaxViews.ToList().ForEach(delegate(EmpowerTaxView etv)
{
    result.Add(etv);   
});
```

Convert to Method Group. What does this mean and what should be done to get rid of this.

Comment: BTW, you don't *have* to "get rid of this": it's not a warning, just a suggestion. If you prefer to keep it in its current form because you find it clearer, it's not a problem.

Comment: Yes, I know, but was curious how to get rid of the error and what method group was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JaredPar already provided the correct answer, I just wanted to suggest a simpler implementation of the method:

```
internal static IList<EmpowerTaxView> GetEmpowerTaxViewsByLongAgencyAndAgencyTaxTypes(
    IList<EmpowerCompanyTaxData> validEmpowerCompanyTaxDatas,
    IList<EmpowerTaxView> empowerTaxViews)
{
    var results =
        from empowerCompanyTaxData in validEmpowerCompanyTaxDatas
        from etv in GetEmpowerTaxViewsByLongAgencyAndTaxType(
            empowerCompanyTaxData, empowerTaxViews)
        select etv;
    return results.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a detailed answer.

Answer (score 70):

What Resharper means is that you can express the `ForEach` code more simply by using the method group `Add`.
Example:

```
validEmpowerTaxViews.ToList().Foreach(result.Add);
```

The method group defined by `Add` is compatible with the delegate expected by `ForEach` and hence the C# compiler will take care of doing the conversion.  The default in Resharper is to prefer method groups over lambdas and explicit delegate creation statements.

Comment: Thanks JaredPar for your suggestion.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer here that attempts to explain the "why".

Comment: I see it's different terminology for eta reduction in functional programming languages such as Haskell where you drop the variable.

Answer (score 7):

Accept Resharper's suggestion to see what changes it makes. You can always undo them.

If you aren't happy with the change and don't want Resharper suggesting it in future then you can disable that specific option - the others will remain available. See the answer here for details.

[Resharper: vars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296783/resharper-vars)

Comment: Thanks for telling me something new!

Answer (score 1):

From [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions) Method group is a set of overloaded methods resulting from a member lookup

You can check inspecting MSIL code that if you use the `method group` then it just makes a new delegate pointing to that method.
But if you use a `lambda expression` then it generates a class with anonymous method under the hood. The result is that method group is required less memory then lambda and Resharper suggests you to optimize