# foreach and method groups

Tags: c#, linq, code-cleanup

Resharper has greatly simplified a loop but now it's bugging me about an unused variable, how do I do this cleanly?

```
foreach (Field Test in Line.Where(IsStartKey))
    Phase = ScanPhase.Processing;
...
private static bool IsStartKey(Field Test)
{
    return Test.Value.StartsWith("Cabinet Name");
}
```

Test was of course used in the original but after the simplification it's useless.  The line is being flagged but no improvements are being suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you don't even need a loop any more. You just need to know if the `Line` has any of the desired items in it. `Enumerable.Any` can do this:

```
if (Line.Any(IsStartKey))
    Phase = ScanPhase.Processing;
```

Comment: Isn't `IsStartKey` expecting a parameter?

Comment: @hatchet It's getting a parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988730/convert-to-method-group-resharper

Comment: @PrestonGuillot - thanks, it's not a feature I've used, so didn't recognize it. @mikez - since we don't know what else is in the foreach loop, can we be sure Any is equivalent? What if there are things in the body that should execute three separate times if there are three items that pass the `IsStartKey` test?

Comment: @hatchet I made what I consider a reasonable assumption, that we have all the relevant code. Many things are possible when you can't see all the code. It's possible that `Phase` is a property that causes side effects that depend on how many times it has been set, in which case this is not equivalent.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  There's nothing fancy going on.  Most of the time I find LINQ makes code less readable and much harder to debug so I stay away from it but occasionally Resharper suggests thing that actually improve it.  I wish it had finished the job here.

Comment: @hatchet The original had a parameter.  Resharper's simplifications already hid it before I got stuck.  There was nothing elaborate here, I just needed to know if any of the items contained the key I was looking for.  Mike was correct in assuming I had posted everything relevant.  Phase is just an enum.